# MySQL select query in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

Can u correct this query? it is show some syntax error.

```
SELECT * 
 WHERE `id` IN (SELECT DISTINCT unit_trust_managing_company_id 
                  FROM ut_funds 
                 ORDER BY `company_name`)
```

There `SELECT DISTINCT unit_trust_managing_company_id FROM ut_funds ORDER BY`company_name` query is working properly.

Comment: **Don't quote/backtick your column names.**  They only add visual clutter and are just one more way for you to make syntax errors.  The only reason you need them is if you have a column name that is a reserved word, and using column names that are reserved words is a terrible idea, so that's two bad habits you can avoid at once.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need a `from` clause before the `where`:

```
SELECT *
FROM <some table here>
WHERE `id` IN (SELECT unit_trust_managing_company_id FROM ut_funds)
```

Also, the `distinct` and `order by` are not needed for the `in` statement.

Comment: if the value of "unit_trust_managing_company_id" is 1,2,3.... this query won't work.... at least in my case... please guide how to rectify this...

Comment: @AsadAliKhan . . . You should ask a question, not a comment.  In any case, storing multiple integer values in a string is the *wrong* way to store values in SQL.  You have a data modeling problem.

Answer (score 0):

In most (all?) cases you can rewrite the query without using the query in the where clause AND get much better performance.  Try something like:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT t.*
    FROM some_table t, ut_funds u
   WHERE t.id=u.unit_trust_managing_company_id
```